# Consulta MySQL con REGEXP para agregar un ID si no está en el valor de un campo

Tags: mysql, regex

Estoy haciendo un sistema en el cual guardo en una base de datos los ID's de los usuarios que van viendo las publicaciones.

Los guardo de la siguiente manera:

```
[562][865][9687][236]...
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario vuelva a visitar la misma publicación, si ya está guardado, si lo visito, no lo vuelva a guardar

Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
UPDATE publicaicones 
SET visto_por = IF(visto_por REGEXP '^.*[[$id_usuario]].*', visto_por, concat(visto_por,'[$id_usuario]'))
WHERE Id = '$id_publicaicon'
```

Pero no funciona.

---

**Luego de ver las recomendaciones para que normalice los datos con otra tabla:**

En mi sistema, los usuarios pueden comentar en las publicaciones, y cuando alguien lo hace, marco como no leída la publicación para los demás usuarios.

Anteriormente yo sólo vaciaba el campo `viso_por`, pero en un esquema normalizado, ¿cómo lo debería hacer? ¿borrar todos los registros? o ¿agregar otra columna a la tabla `publicaciones_vistas`?.

También comentar que marco aquellas publicaciones que son nuevas para diferenciarlas de aquellas en las que comentaron, antes lo hacia con otra columna en la que no vaciaba los Id's cuando alguien comentaba, ¿ahora como lo debería hacer?, ¿con otra tabla?

Comment: Antes de contestar, ¿por qué lo estás guardando en ese formato? ¿no sería más sencillo en diferentes filas de la base de datos? Y en caso de que necesites sí o sí tenerlo en 1 solo campo, ¿no te conviene separar por comas? y aún cuando sigas usando corchetes, ¿por qué estás intentando usar `regexp` y no algo más sencillo como `like`?

Comment: Además, esa sintaxis no es de MySQL. ¿Estás pasando un string desde PHP? ¿o qué lenguaje?

Comment: Diría que la escalabilidad de esto va a ser mala si tienes muchos usuarios y muchas visitas.. por qué de-normalizarlo de esta manera?

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta directa a tu pregunta es:

La sintaxis de doble corchetes es para equivalencias Unicode, que no está relacionado a tu pregunta. En cambio, para escapar un corchete `[` y que el motor de expresiones regulares lo tome como literal, se debe usar `\[`. Para el id `562`, la expresión regular quedaría:

```regex
\[562]
```

Pero MySQL también interpreta la `\` como un escape, por lo que se debería escapar nuevamente en la sentencia:

```sql
UPDATE publicaicones 
SET visto_por = IF(visto_por REGEXP '\\[562]', 
                   visto_por, 
                   concat(visto_por,'[562]')
                  )
WHERE Id = 1;
```

Y además, PHP también usa la `\` como escape, y tenemos que escaparlo nuevamente:

```php
<?php
$id_usuario = "562";
$query = "UPDATE publicaicones 
          SET visto_por = IF(visto_por REGEXP '\\\\[$id_usuario]', 
                             visto_por, 
                             concat(visto_por,'[$id_usuario]')
                            )
          WHERE Id = '$id_publicaicon';";
```

Con esto solucionarías el problema que estás teniendo con la expresión regular, pero no es la solución que recomendaría.

---

El problema central de tu pregunta está relacionado al diseño de la base de datos. Realmente, los campos que reúnen diferentes valores es justamente lo que **no se debería hacer**. Un buen diseño en la base de datos siempre debería tener valores ***[normalizados](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos)***. En vez de reunir todo dentro de un mismo campo, la opción más recomendable es utilizar una tabla para guardar qué usuarios vieron cada publicación. Algo similar a la siguiente estructura:

```
+-----+------------+------------+-----------------+
|                 publicaicones                   |
+-----+------------+------------+-----------------+
| Id  |   Campo1   |   Campo2   | ...otros campos |
+-----+------------+------------+-----------------+
|   1 | valor 1, 1 | valor 1, 2 | etc. 1          |
|   2 | valor 2, 1 | valor 2, 2 | etc. 2          |
| ... | ...        | ...        | ...             |
+-----+------------+------------+-----------------+
```

```
+----------------+------------+
|    publicaciones_vistas     |
+----------------+------------+
| Id_Publicacion | Id_Usuario |
+----------------+------------+
|              1 |        562 |
|              1 |        865 |
|              1 |       9687 |
|              1 |        236 |
|              2 |        562 |
|            ... |        ... |
+----------------+------------+
```

De esta forma, todas las operaciones que quieras realizar se simplifican astronómicamente. Así es como deberías estructurar tu base de datos.

*¿Podés imaginarte cuál de los dos diseños es más sencillo cuando quieras obtener la lista de publicaciones que vio un usuario dado?*

Así es como los motores de base de datos fueron diseñados para trabajar y la forma profesional de realizarlo.

---

> en un esquema normalizado, ¿cómo lo debería hacer? ¿borrar todos los registros? o ¿agregar otra columna a la tabla `publicaciones_vistas`?

Sí, siguiendo la misma lógica que habías implementado inicialmente, en vez de borrar un campo con todos los IDs agregados, se borrarían todas las filas que tengan el ID de la publicación. Por ejemplo, para marcar que ningún usuario vio la publicación con `ID = 1`, sería tan sencillo como:

```sql
delete 
  from publicaciones_vistas
 where Id_Publicacion = 1;
```

> marco aquellas publicaciones que son nuevas para diferenciarlas de aquellas en las que comentaron, antes lo hacia con otra columna en la que no vaciaba los Id's cuando alguien comentaba, ¿ahora como lo debería hacer?, ¿con otra tabla?

Sí, sin duda la mejor recomendación que puedo darte es que lo manejes en una tabla diseñada para grabar estos datos. Podría ser de dos formas:

1. Por timestamp
   Con 1 sola tabla, grabando la fecha y hora en la que un usuario la vio por última vez, y luego consultando por los usuarios cuyo timestamp es mayor que el timestamp de la última modificación.
2. Con 2 tablas
   Una tabla para *publicaciones vistas*, marcando si alguna vez la vieron.
   Otra tabla con *publicaciones revisadas*, marcando si la vieron luego de la edición.
   Ambas, con ID de publicación y ID de usuario.